# How to identify a GKE preemptted node event

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to tell BEFORE a preemptible node is actually preempted? I can tell that GCE logs an event WHEN it happens (the `compute.instances.preempted` event), but is there a way to tell within GKE *before* it happens so that I can take preventive measures?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is no longer true in 2023, according to Google's documentation. There are two options:

1. Some kind of coordinator application can make requests to Google's API to detect pre-emptions (and optionally send its own signal to the VM/spot pod to notify it of its pre-emption). The provided link has more instructions on how to scope down to pre-emption zone operations.

`GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE/operations`

2. A pre-empted VM or spot pod can detect its own pre-emption.

`curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/preempted" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-use-spot#detect-preemption

Comment: thank you for the update. I *had* seen that it'd changed, but I'd forgotten that I had this question and that it could be updated. I've changed the answering tick to reflect 2023.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect when a Google VM is going to be preempted. [There is a delay to allow shut down scripts to run](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible), but there is no warning that the instance is being preempted before the fact to allow you to prepare for it. This is one of the risks you accept when using preemptible VMs.

It is not explicitly mentioned that there will be no notice, but the lack of notification process implies that you will not be notified before hand. [This section on GPU preemptible VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) explicitly mentions that to get notifications you need to use standard VMs

Comment: Ugh... I was hoping I was wrong. >.<
Apparently AWS Spot instances give a couple of minutes warning in the form of an event, so I was hoping for the same thing. Thank you!